# Connected to the remote computer using the Web Management Service, but could not authorize

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azureportal

When I am at the last step of publishing my web APP, I got stuck by this:

> Connected to the remote computer xxxxx using the Web Management
>   Service, but could not authorize. Make sure that you are using the
>   correct user name and password, that the site you are connecting to
>   exists, and that the credentials represent a user who has permissions
>   to access the site.  Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED.)

I used all default settings.
I am using Visual Studio 2015 and I can access the new Azure portal.

Thanks

Derek